# Theos make: *** [internal-install] Error 1

Tags: jailbreak, theos

i will start developing jailbreak tweaks. I started with this tutorial: 
http://brandontreb.com/beginning-jailbroken-ios-development-building-and-deployment/

i get the following error with this command

```
sudo make package install

/Users/.../fooproject/theos/makefiles/targets/Darwin/iphone.mk:41:
Deploying to iOS 3.0 while building for 6.0 will generate armv7-only binaries.
Making all for application fooProject...
Copying resource directories into the application wrapper...
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `internal-application-compile'.
Making stage for application fooProject...
dpkg-deb: Baue Paket »com.alex.fooproject« in »./com.alex.fooproject_0.0.1-12_iphoneos-  arm.deb«.
make install requires that you set THEOS_DEVICE_IP in your environment. It is also      recommended that you have public-key authentication set up for root over SSH, or you'll be entering your password a lot.
make: *** [internal-install] Error 1
```

Okay the Variable THEOS_DEVICE_IP is set. I did it with this command:

```
export THEOS_DEVICE_IP=192.168.178.39
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put the THEOS_DEVICE_IP = 192.0.0.0 in first line of your makefile.

Comment: Please expand on your answer

Comment: You can put it on the makefile but it's not needed.

Comment: doesn´t solve the problem. ssh connection to my iphone works.

Comment: It does solve the problem. It's just need to be the first line!

Answer (score 8):

You just should put

```
THEOS_DEVICE_IP = 192.168.2.4
```

at your **first** line of your Make file.

Answer (score 1):

before `make` command use this command

```
export SDKVERSION=6.0
```

where 6.0 is your ios sdk version